# Google Keyboard vs Android Keyboard (AOSP)

Tags: keyboard, gboard

Is there a difference between [Google Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin), which was recently release on the Play Store, and the Android Keyboard (AOSP) in the open source project?

Update: I need the difference from a feature prospective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly the same keyboard as the Android Keyboard from Jelly Bean (4.2) as I read.
See i.e. [this](http://www.engadget.com/2013/06/05/google-stock-android-keyboard-to-play-store/) article.

Rereading exactly points out that this app should expose the keyboard which was only installed on Nexus phones with Android 4.2 to prior android version (4.0+) on other smartphones and tablets including features like "swiping" and gestures.

[There is another article on Androidcentral](http://www.androidcentral.com/google-keyboard-now-available-directly-google-play)

Answer (score 1):

My AOSP keyboard let me long press some of the keys for punctuation.  I could hold "m" to get a "?" and now I no longer can on the Google Keyboard.

Comment: You can press the 123 key and whilst holding it slide to the where the m key was, which will now be displaying a ?  This is a quick way of getting to the numbers, too.  Likewise, you can slide from the shift key to capitalise a single character.

Comment: This is probably the CyanogenMod keyboard, which is titled `Android Keyboard (AOSP)` and has the symbols on every key.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand The AOSP keyboard is available in CM Roms, its called 'stock' keyboard when you flash CM based ROMS. As for Google Keyboard, it's the official one on Nexus devices. I personally like the CM (AOSP) Keyboard. It allows me to long press keys for punctuations, I'm very used to long pressing 'm' for '?' and 'z' for '!'. It is irritating that I can't do that on the Official keyboard. I also can't find a separate APK for the CM (AOSP) Keyboard

Comment: There is EnhancedIME which is apparently the AOSP keyboard with some enhancements: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/enhancedime-aosp-latinime-enhancements-t3366639